# Typing an Enter key in Selenium

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate the site in selenium. I want to search an item on the search bar but there is no button to click “search” or “go”. Is there a quick way to type an enter or return key in Selenium. Unfortunately the form I’m trying to test (not my own code so I can’t modify) doesn’t have a submit button. When working with it manually, I just type enter or return, and just need to know how to do that with the Selenium “type” command

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keydown` command with code `\13` to perform enter action

```
 keyDown  | id=search(locator of your search field)  |  \13
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. I tried the command you mentioned above but it does not clicks enter when I run the script. My Locator is id=search. Is there any way around I can try as this only finds it but not select it. <input id="search" type="search">